# Extract variable names from file

Tags: python, sed

I have a text file containing a large number of lines like this.

```
NOTE: Variable Variable_S1 already exists on file D1.D, using Var_S8 instead.  
NOTE: The variable name more_than_eight_letters_m has been truncated to ratio_s.  
NOTE: Variable ratio_s already exists on file D1.D, using Var_S9 instead.
```

I am trying to create a list containing 2 columns :

```
Variable_S1 Var_S8   
more_than_eight_letters Var_S9
```

Can someone tell me how to do this using sed or python or even R ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You want to remove all words without underscores, then combine lines where the second word of one line is the same as the first word of the other, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about sed or R, but in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> i = """NOTE: Variable Variable_S1 already exists on file D1.D, using Var_S8 instead.
NOTE: The variable name more_than_eight_letters_m has been truncated to ratio_s.
NOTE: Variable ratio_s already exists on file D1.D, using Var_S9 instead."""
>>> print(re.findall(r'(\w+_\w+)', i))
['Variable_S1', 'Var_S8', 'more_than_eight_letters_m', 'ratio_s', 'ratio_s', 'Var_S9']
```

Here is an improved version, which will give you the set of variables for each line:

```
>>> print([re.findall(r'(\w+_\w+)', line) for line in i.split('\n')])
[['Variable_S1', 'Var_S8'],
 ['more_than_eight_letters_m', 'ratio_s'],
 ['ratio_s', 'Var_S9']]
```